# Aggregating and summing rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      id   string     value
1     a    apple      2
2     a    banana     5
3     b    orange     1
4     b    grape      3
5     c    pear       6
```

I want to aggregate the strings and sum the values based on the id to look something like this:

```
      id   string            value
1     a    apple, banana     7
2     b    orange, grape     4
3     c    pear              6
```

I've tried

```
aggregate(. ~ id, dataframe, sum)
```

but it returns `"Error: in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument".`
I'm not sure what else may work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(string = toString(string), value = sum(value))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  id    string        value
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 a     apple, banana     7
2 b     orange, grape     4
3 c     pear              6
```